# Saving data in useState variable with select form in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, use-state

I have an array of objects which contain properties of their size and quantity (FE: {size:"Large", quantity: 10}). I want the user to be able to select any available size in the form and then store it in useState. To be honset I do something like that for the first time and sadly my code is not working. I get basillion errors starting with "event is undeffined". I'm pasting my code below:

```
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setChosenSize(event.target.value)
    }

    const choseSize = (array) => {
        return (<>
             <form>
                <label>Choos your size:</label>
                <select onChange={() => handleChange()}>
                    {array.map((object) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={object.size}>{object.size}: {object.quantity}</option>
                    )
                    })}
                </select>
            </form>
        </>)
    }
    console.log(chosenSize)
```

Comment: If you need to access the event in your handler, then you should either patch it through `onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}` or simply provide your handler directly `onChange={handleChange}`

Comment: Where's the array?

Comment: Can you show more code to see how are you using  use state. The undefined event error is coming because you are not passing the event in onChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the function without passing anything inside it so `event` will either be undefined or null. The following should fix your problem:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setChosenSize(event.target.value)
    }

    const choseSize = (array) => {
        return (<>
             <form>
                <label>Choos your size:</label>
                <select onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>
                    {array.map((object) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={object.size}>{object.size}: {object.quantity}</option>
                    )
                    })}
                </select>
            </form>
        </>)
    }
    console.log(chosenSize)
```

or you can do the following (which I prefer)

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setChosenSize(event.target.value)
    }

    const choseSize = (array) => {
        return (<>
             <form>
                <label>Choos your size:</label>
                <select onChange={handleChange}>
                    {array.map((object) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={object.size}>{object.size}: {object.quantity}</option>
                    )
                    })}
                </select>
            </form>
        </>)
    }
    console.log(chosenSize)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!